# Chaquopy: Python: Is there any way to run Django Apps on Android

Tags: python, android, django, chaquopy

I've made a Django Web App which I want to deploy on Android.
Recently, I came across a gradle plugin **Chaquopy**.
But as soon as I deploy django app using Chaquopy, It doesn't give desired result and rather gives runtime exceptions.
Kindly describe any method using (or even without using) Chaquopy to deploy Django App on Android as .apk

Comment: do you want to transform your web site to android app ?

Comment: if you want to transform your web app in android  you can use https://gonative.io/ and if you want to build your own you can try to create an api using django and serving your app with that.

Comment: @amadousow, Yeah! You may be right but that's not the question.

Comment: Hi, I'm the creator of Chaquopy. I know of at least one person who successfully ran Django on Android using Chaquopy, so it should be possible. Please create an issue on our [GitHub page](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues) giving details of the exceptions you received, along with the relevant code.

Comment: Thank you dear developer @mhsmith 
Thanks a lot